# Setting up DNS forward zone when AD domain name is a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, subdomain, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm in high school and want to learn about system administration, so I set up a Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller in a lab and created the domain ***ad.foo.com***. I own ***foo.com*** and the domain registrar (Gandi) handles the DNS and hosts my personal website.

In my lab, I've installed the DNS role on the domain controller but I'm unsure of what the Forward Lookup Zone for the domain should be. The DNS "New Zone" wizard says:

> The zone name specifies the portion of the DNS namespace for which
>   this server is authoritative. [...]

I only want the DNS Server to handle the computers in my lab's ad.foo.com domain, so is putting ***ad.foo.com*** the correct thing to do?

I appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Typically the forward lookup zone for "ad.foo.com" would have been automatically created by the `dcpromo` process. It's kinda odd that it wasn't created for you.

Comment: @EvanAnderson The Forward Lookup Zone is created but I was questioning whether ***ad.foo.com*** is correct when I own ***foo.com*** and ***foo.com***'s DNS is handled by the registrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Your internal DNS server will be authoritative for **ad.foo.com**. Your external DNS server(s) will be authoritative for **foo.com**.

Comment: This is what I thought but wasn't sure if it was correct. Thank you.